# Query from 3 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables: `TblUsers`, `tblBridge`, and `tblAssignments`.

The bridge contains the ID of the user and the corresponding AssignmentID for that user.

I'm trying to find the user with a certain assignment `@Assignment`, but also where `tblUser.isAdmin = Yes`.

I feel like its possible with Joins, I just can't find a good example on how to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.* FROM tblBridge b
JOIN tblUsers u ON u.ID = b.tblUsersID
JOIN tblAssignments a ON a.ID = b.tblAssignmentsID
WHERE u.isAdmin = 'yes' AND a.name = 'searched assignment'
```

It's MANY-TO-MANY Relation so you need select many-to-many table and join it to assigments and users also put in where condition for admin.

I'm not sure if the names are exact the same as you have in your DB so you need adjust it to yor needs.

I don't know the field that you look for in assigment table so change `a.name` to your needs.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you. Would have taken me awhile to get that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is in a stored procedure which receives an `@assignment` var.

```
select tu.[Users] from TblUsers tu 
join tblBridge tb on tu.id=tb.TblUsersid
join tblAssignments ta on ta.id = tb.tblAssignmentsid
where ta.[Assignment] = @Assignment
and tu.[isAdmin] = 'Yes'
```